# How to access calendar information from Microsoft Outlook Exchange 2010 SP2

Tags: calendar, outlook, icalendar

I want to make a website with this capability:
We have 5 people who all have individual calendars on Outlook Exchange 2010 SP2. I want the website to have one calendar that shows any available spots. Who's calendar it comes from doesn't matter. So if two people have two spots available at 10am the calendar would only show that there is a 10am spot open. It doesn't matter which person the client goes to. I'm trying to figure how to access the Calendars data but have no idea where to start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using EWS (Exchange Web Services). See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information.